# Show proper item that matches desired reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

My issue is that I cannot show the exact information that needs to be viewed in table.

So for example, let's say I have a button `Show` and I retrieve an array of objects:

```
"data": [
           {
             "short_desc": "Lorem Ipsum Short",
             "long_desc": "Lorem Ipsum Long",
           },
           {
             "short_desc": "Lorem Ipsum Short",
             "long_desc": "Lorem Ipsum Long",
           }
       ]
```

So I have a table with two rows and two buttons in each row - `Show`. On first click it should show first object, and on second it should show second object. So, match the keys in the array with proper `Show` button. How can I achieve this?

I know this is probably an 'old question', but I've been log away from programming and forgot this algorithm.

Thanks.

EDIT: Edited following the comment.

So, I first I receive data:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'url'
}).done(function(res) {
    var data = res.data 
    // here logic goes
})
```

Data is shown now with `Show` button.

Now I need to make a handler to Show exact data on button click.

Comment: First array , seoncd array ? I see only one array ! could you explain correctly your  question

Comment: @bRIMOs, hi, edited. Is it more clear now?

Comment: what does the two buttons do , here only one is sufficient

Comment: Each button should show keys from proper object. So first `show` should show elements in the first object, and second `show` button should show elements in the second object. 

It will be accordion, but that's not important. I need to find a way to match each `show` with proper index.. So 1st `Show` button =`data[0].short_desc`
2nd `Show` button = `data[1].short_desc`

Comment: @bRIMOs, also It can be 2 or more buttons, this isn't something I can control. Hence I need different solution that the one posted bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this is what you are searching for , the below snippet shows matched `data-id` object on btn click using jquery

```js
var json = {
  "data": [{
      "short_desc": "Lorem Ipsum Short 1",
      "long_desc": "Lorem Ipsum Long 1 ",
    },
    {
      "short_desc": "Lorem Ipsum Short 2 ",
      "long_desc": "Lorem Ipsum Long 2 ",
    },
    {
      "short_desc": "Lorem Ipsum Short 3 ",
      "long_desc": "Lorem Ipsum Long 3 ",
    }
  ]
}

$(".btn").on("click",function(){
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  if(!isNaN(id)) {
    var data = json.data[id-1];
    if(data){
      $("#short").html(data.short_desc);
      $("#long").html(data.short_desc);
    }
    else {
      $("#short").html("");
      $("#long").html("");
    }
  }
  else {
    $("#short").html("");
    $("#long").html("");
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="btn" data-id="1">Show 1</button></td>
    <td><button class="btn" data-id="2">Show 2</button></td>
    <td><button class="btn" data-id="3">Show 3</button></td>
    <td><button class="btn" data-id="4">Show  no data</button></td>
  <tr>
<table>

<div>
  <div>
  Short desc : 
    <p id="short"><p>
  </div>
  <div>
  long desc :
    <p id="long"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this waht you were searching for , otherwise , just tell what is wrong

Comment: Sorry for late response. Unfortunately - no, because my objects come from async calls.

Comment: so could you just post the code to see the how to make logic for this last

Comment: Edited, can you please see now? Thanks

Because of nature of async call I cannot get the elements as they are attached in the JavaScript asynchronously.

Comment: have you tried to put the button click event inside the response function , so after loading data the event is attached to that button

Answer (score 0):

You could give each button its own class, so that you can distinguish them, e.g. in jQuery:

```
$(buttons).on('click',
              function () {
                  if ($(this).hasClass('firstButton'))
                         // show first button
                  else if ($(this).hasClass('secondButton'))
                         // show second button
               });
```

For many buttons, you could give each one an incremental ID when you're writing them, plus the relevant classes. Then, as well as checking for `hasClass`, you can also use `$(this).attr('id')` and between the two of them should be possible to identify which precise array element is needed.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I know this, but I need something that would match multiple buttons. What if there are more than 10 buttons?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a suggestion for ramping this up to multiple buttons, hope it helps.

Comment: Is there a better way, not to bind to element attributes?